# Vk api не получается отправить через бота опрос

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я новичок, который пытается реализовать рассылку опросов через вк бота. Порядок действий:

1. Ты пишешь личные сообщения боту /опрос и во вложениях создаёшь опрос.
2. Бот обрабатывает сообщение и пересылает опрос в группу с этим ботом.

Проблема заключается в том, что опрос создаётся, ошибки никакие не вылетают, а опрос не отсылается. Скорее всего моя проблема целиком и полностью лежит в неправильной передаче attachment/создании формата опроса. Для примера вот код (который пока что пишется в группе с ботом и он должен переслать в неё же моё сообщение с опросом) и ссылка на опрос, который я пытаюсь отправить:

Опрос - https://vk.com/poll318377923_755830266 ( Здесь дал себе понять что форматирую его правильно по части poll318377923_755830266 )

```
res_att = event.obj.message['attachments'][0]['poll'] 
poll_send = 'poll{}_{}'.format(res_att['owner_id'], res_att['id'])
message_send(vk_session, event, "Text", attachment = poll_send)
```

Данные строки кода выводят мне poll318377923_755830266, что схоже с кодом от ВК, но даже когда я пытаюсь вывести message_send(vk_session, event, "Text", attachment = 'poll318377923_755830266') у меня не выходит это сделать.

Функция message_send принимает:

```
def message_send(session, event = None, message = None, attachment = None, id = None, isUser = False, keyboard = None, sticker_id = None):
```

Спасибо за уделённое время !

Comment: Вы используете сообщество или пользователя? Я попробовал, у меня вроде как работает. Попробуйте прямо сейчас повторить.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать следующее:
1)Делать запрос, указав User-Agent, характерный для оф.приложения ВКонтакте (например, `VKAndroidApp/7.35-11000`),
2)Передавать только id опроса, т.е. `attachment = 'poll755830266'`, хоть это и противоречит документации, но у меня это почему-то сработало.

Comment: Привет! Решил попробовать то, что ты написал. 1) Никак не помог мне, но 2) пункт вывел мне опрос, но он (poll755830266 ), не создан мною. Удивительно что все данные с опроса мои, но то, что он вывел никогда не создавалось мною.
Я пробовал выводить опрос в беседе вк вместе с ботом. Делал следующие:
1) Создавал опрос и отправлял его 
2) Получал данные, форматировал их и передавал их в attachment.
К сожалению от меня так не работает. даже если я передаю именно свой id опроса. Также ты сказал, что у тебя получилось вывести это, можешь прикрепить код где у тебя это получилось ? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Думаю, у нас разница в том, что я от имени пользователя отправляю опрос в сообщении, а ты от имени бота (группы). Я пользуюсь неофициальным модулем VK API для Питона, но не думаю, что там есть какая-то принципиальная разница. С помощью `requests.post` делается запрос к методу `polls.create` и затем к `messages.send`. Версия API передаётся `v='5.131'` в обоих случаях.

Comment: К сожалению все методы в разделе polls не относятся к группе. Поэтому я не могу использовать их. Должен быть другой способ отправки опроса пользователя через бота. Спасибо за ответ!